# Bokeh.patches gives wrong result

Tags: python, gis, bokeh

I have the source shp file in the projection EPSG 3857.

Source SHP:
[image: Source SHP]

Now I'm trying to create an interactive map using bokeh

```
river_fp = r"shp/test.shp"

river = gpd.read_file(river_fp)

geojson = river.to_json()

CRS = river.crs
print(CRS)

geo_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = geojson)
p = figure(title = "Rivers")

p.patches('xs', 'ys', fill_alpha = 0.1, 
          line_color = 'blue', line_width = 0.5, source = geo_source)

out_fp = "interactive_map.html"
save(p, out_fp)
```

Result map:
[image: Result map]

The result was not in that projection and some data was incorrectly reflected on the map. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`Patches` does not support "holes". If you need that (which it appears from your first image that you do), then you will need to use [`MultiPolygons`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html?highlight=multipolygons#polygons-with-holes). I am not otherwise sure about the data formats involved so the best I can do is point you in that direction.